# first fetch method in for loop running before any other methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm writing a program that requires me to run three fetch methods sequentially over each object in an array. Because each method is setting state, after I set the state, I attach a callback method that calls the next function.

I tried my naive thought of simply calling the functions one after the other with no callback, but since each function is modifying state, that does not work.

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    this.executeA(array[i]);
}

executeA(data){
   fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/a', headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
       .then((response) => {
           response.json().then((res) => {
               this.setState({ a: res }, () => {
                   executeB(data);
               });
           });
        })

}

executeB(data){
   fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/b', headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
       .then((response) => {
           response.json().then((res) => {
               this.setState({ b: res }, () => {
                   execute(data);
               });
           });
        })
}

executeC(data){
   fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/c', headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
       .then((response) => {
           response.json().then((res) => {
               this.setState({ c: res }, () => {
                   console.log(this.state.c);
               });
           });
        })
}
```

For example, I would expect the order of operations for an array of length 3 to be A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C. Instead, the order of execution is A,A,A,B,C,B,C,B,C. I'm not quite sure why the first method executes for each object in the array before any other method gets called, as I thought that after it sets the state, the callback method would move onto the next function. Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: what is `//fetch stuff`?

Comment: @Vencovsky that's a call made to an api, will update the question now

Answer (score 0):

If you have some promise going on, you should propably use `async/await` and in the for loop use `await` too.

```
const someFunc = async () => {    
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        await this.executeA(array[i]); 
    }
}
```

And also add `async/await` in `//fetch stuff`

The reason why you get `AAABBBCCC` is that in the for loop, you don't await the first `A` to complete to call the second `A`. You just pass through all `A` really fast.

Comment: That won't work because `this.setState` doesn't return a `Promise`

Comment: I'm not the one that posted the question but even if you `await` the `// fetch stuff` you cannot await `this.setState`, you'll have to create a `Promise` for it.

Comment: What he does is `this.setState({ c: res }` and looking at the variable name,  `res` is probably from a fetch call or maybe something like `axios` so this means that he is setting state inside a promise already, so yes, he can use `await/async`. Just add the code of `//fetch stuff` and it will be easier to solve

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `executeA` returns as soon as `this.setState` is called (doesn't wait for the callback function passed to it to return) and that is true for all your functions. To keep this synchronised you can create new promises and fulfil them after the state is set, here is an example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    await this.executeA(array[i]);
}

async executeA(data){
    const res = await fetch(....)
    return new Promise(resolve => this.setState({ b: res }, async () => {
            await executeB(data);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

async executeB(data){
    const res = await fetch(....)
    return new Promise(resolve => this.setState({ b: res }, async () => {
            await executeC(data);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

async executeC(data){
    const res = await fetch(....)
    return new Promise(resolve => this.setState({ c: res }, resolve));
}
```

Comment: How does the first `await` work without being wrapped in an `async function`?

Comment: @zer00ne This code is not meant to be run as is, is just an example to illustrate a way of solving the problem.

Comment: Syntactically that part fails and does not help illustrate your point. If this is an example of code that does not work then you have succeeded. Typos do not help either (see third `fetch()` spelt as `fatch(....)`)

Comment: @zer00ne I've fixed the `fatch` which was more of an inconsistency then a typo. This example is kind of pseudocode, the `await` inside the loop is not the only JavaScript syntax error, having functions declared like that outside of a class' body is a syntax error as well. My goal was to keep this example close to the OP's example so he can understand it.

Comment: if setting state in React implies that the entire code be a `class` (I really have no idea React still seems to me a lot of work and boilerplate for very little gain) you should provide the proper code and an explanation. It is important that OP grok but it is just as important that future readers grok as well.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is pretty similar to other people's answers except it's a working example. I hope it helps.

```js
//* this part is just for testing
function fetchStuff(key) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), Math.random()*1000);
  });
}
//*/

const array = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

async function runFor(elem) {
  //* this part is just for testing
  console.log('runFor', elem);
  this.setState = function(state) {
    console.log('setState', state);
  };
  //*/
  
  await fetchStuff('a').then(res => {
    this.setState({a: res});
  });
  await fetchStuff('b').then(res => {
    this.setState({b: res});
  });
  await fetchStuff('c').then(res => {
    this.setState({c: res});
  });
}

async function main() {
  for (let elem of array) {
    await runFor(elem);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: I'm not the down voter but I think the problem is that the OP tagged the question as `reactjs` which means that `this.setState` is part of React and the way he users it, it means he wants to wait for the state to change before calling another function.